# Webpack: Refer currently processing file name in configs

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, webpack-4, bundling-and-minification

I am trying to replace a string with the filename in webpack bundling. Is there a way I can get the webpack config to give me the file name of the currently processing file? So that I can use it with the `webpack-plugin-replace` somwthing like ,

```
plugins: [
...
    new ReplacePlugin({
      values: {
        '__CUSTOM_STRING': CURRENTLY_PROCESSING_FILENAME,
      }
    })
  ]
```

Note: The `__filename` solution is not working for me as I am using angular-cli to build not webpack directly.
Referring `__filename` in Angular components gives `Cannot find name __filename` error.

Answer (score 0):

Yep there is one:[__filename](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-variables/#__filename-nodejs)

But by default webpack doesn't leak path information and you need to set a config flag to get real filename instead of a mock `("/index.js")`.

```
// /home/project/webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  node: {
    __filename: true
  }
}
```

Than you can use __filename get the current filename relative to the context option:

```
// in /home/project/dir/file.js
console.log(__filename);
// => logs "dir/file.js"
```

The filename is only embedded into modules where `__filename` is used. So you don't have to be affraid that paths are leaked from other modules.

Comment: Thanks! In fact, I tried this solution. It works, except that I am using angular-cli to build, not directly webpack. When I attempt __filename, Angular throws `cannot find name __filename`. I will update my question to include angular info too. 
Could you help with a workaround this?